# How to make the TypeScript path maps useful in the production code?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I've been working on my TypeScript project and wanted to tackle the relative import `../../../` hell problem. I found out that in `tsconfig.json` I can specify the `baseUrl` and `paths` fields so that my `../../../../interface` can become simply `@interface` when I add such a snippet to the `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@interface" : ["src/interface"],
    },
```

and that worked great... for a while. I exchanged the long paths in import statements with shorter versions. VSCode was kind enough to understand the path mapping and coding became easier. When I finally wanted to test the app, I compiled the code with `tsc` command. When I wanted to run it, I got the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@interface'
```

I inspected the output JavaScript code and saw that the path in the import has not been exchanged by the compiler, as I would expect, but it was just used in the same form as in the `.ts` file:

```
const _interface_1 = require("@interface");
```

I found [an issue on TS GitHub from August 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722) asking about the exact same thing. Until now there has not been a satisfying solution to the problem.

My question is: what is the use case for the path mapping in TypeScript [as described in the manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)? What's the point of using them if they in the end make the production code not runnable?

Comment: I think the logic (which I also don't agree with) is to not touch the javascript behavior, typescript module aliases are for typescript's use. Once you run javascript - it's up to you to setup module aliasing in whatever you use. Webpack has one solution, running in node.js has another. Presumably other module bundlers will also behave differently. 

Is there a real use case where you'll setup module aliasing in runtime differently than in typescript build time? might be, I haven't seen one yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also agree with the comment Aviad has put but without judging. If you must do this, then here is a way:

Add module `module-alias` to your dependencies. then add mapping to package.json too:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
    "@interface": "dist/interface", // note its referencing dist folder
},
```

Then in your main ts file. e.g. `index.ts`, register the module alias using `import "module-alias/register";`

[Here you can read more about it](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias)